# Typecasting Error in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, typecasting-operator

```
pop=x.nextSibling()[0]  # pop="Population: 1,414,204"
pre_result=pop.text.split(" ") #pre_result=['Population:','1,414,204']
a=pre_result[1] # a='1,414,204'
result=int(a) #Error pops over here.Tried int(a,2) by searching answers in internet still got an error.
print(result) 
print(type(result))
```

The following is the error message.I thought typecasting from str to int would be simple but still i came across this error.I am a beginner in python so sorry if there has been any silly mistake in my code.

```
File "C:\Users\Latheesh\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Population Graph.py", line 14, in getPopulation
    result=int(a)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1,373,541,278'
```

Comment: What is not clear about this? How would Python parse '`1,373,541,278'` directly?

Comment: using commata to separate numbers is unusual outside of (I think) central europe, so you have to remove them before parsing

Comment: Lol i got it.I realise now how stupid of a question this was lmao.Thanks guys!

Comment: no problem, happens to everyone =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is self explaining, `a` contains the string `'1,373,541,278'`, and that is not a format Python can handle.

We can however remove the comma's from the string, with:

```
result=int(a.replace(',', ''))
```

But it is possible that for some elements, you will have to do additional processing.

Comment: It did work thank you :)